# find specific nodes in d3js tree

Tags: d3.js, tree, nodes

I am trying to find specific nodes on the tree layout.  I found this example on plunkr:

```
function collapse(d) {
if (d.children) {
  d._children = d.children;
  d._children.forEach(function(d1){d1.parent = d; collapse(d1);});
  d.children = null;
}}
function find(d, name) {
if (d.name == name){
  while(d.parent){
    d = d.parent;
    click(d)
  }
  return;
}
if (d.children) {
  d.children.forEach(function(d){find(d, name)});
} else if(d._children){
  d._children.forEach(function(d){find(d, name)});
}}
[root].forEach(collapse);
var name = "layout"
find (root, name)
update(root);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ce5Ub8PWXblSMcrYlkHa?p=preview which finds a specif node given a name.  
I adopted it to find a node given an ID.
I have two problems with the implementation:

1- The code generates an error in the console "Error:  attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(undefined,undefi…".  Which I think is due to the x and y coordinates becoming null, but I cannot identify the exact condition.  This error appears in the original example as well.

2- If I call the find routine once (by clicking the find button which calls find_name() and commenting out the second call to the find function) , it works, however if I call it more than once (by un-commenting and enabling the second call to find), the tree collapses to the root node.

Any help in understanding this behavior is much appreciated.

```js
<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 
<script>

// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************

var data =[{"sid":"1","parent":"null","name_ar":"Hashim"},{"sid":"2","parent":"1","name_ar":"wahb"},{"sid":"3","parent":"1","name_ar":"Abdulmuttaleb"},{"sid":"4","parent":"2","name_ar":"Amina"},{"sid":"5","parent":"3","name_ar":"Abutaleb"},{"sid":"6","parent":"3","name_ar":"Abdulla"},{"sid":"7","parent":"3","name_ar":"Abbas"},{"sid":"8","parent":"3","name_ar":"Hamza"},{"sid":"9","parent":"6","name_ar":"Mohammed (Prophet)"},{"sid":"10","parent":"9","name_ar":"Alqassim"},{"sid":"11","parent":"9","name_ar":"Um Kalthoum"},{"sid":"12","parent":"9","name_ar":"Zainab"},{"sid":"13","parent":"9","name_ar":"Ruqaya"},{"sid":"14","parent":"9","name_ar":"Fatima"},{"sid":"15","parent":"9","name_ar":"Ibrahim"},{"sid":"16","parent":"9","name_ar":"Abdulla"},{"sid":"17","parent":"9","name_ar":"Muhsen"},{"sid":"18","parent":"5","name_ar":"Ali"},{"sid":"19","parent":"18","name_ar":"Hassan"},{"sid":"20","parent":"18","name_ar":"Hussain"},{"sid":"21","parent":"20","name_ar":"Ali Zain Alabbideen"},{"sid":"22","parent":"21","name_ar":"Mohammed Baqer"},{"sid":"23","parent":"22","name_ar":"Jafar Sadeq"},{"sid":"24","parent":"23","name_ar":"Mousa Kadim"},{"sid":"25","parent":"24","name_ar":"Ali AlAreed"},{"sid":"26","parent":"24","name_ar":"Ibrahim Murtada"},{"sid":"27","parent":"26","name_ar":"Mousa (the second)"},{"sid":"28","parent":"27","name_ar":"Ahmed"},{"sid":"29","parent":"28","name_ar":"Hussain"},{"sid":"30","parent":"29","name_ar":"Abu Alqassim Mohammed"},{"sid":"31","parent":"30","name_ar":"Najm Aldeen Mahdi"}];

//------------------
//the find function is global
function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(function(d1){d1.parent = d; collapse(d1);});
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  function find(d, sid) {
    if (d.sid == sid){
      while(d.parent){
        d = d.parent;
        click(d)
      }
      return;
    }
    if (d.children) {
      d.children.forEach(function(d){find(d, sid)});
    } else if(d._children){
      d._children.forEach(function(d){find(d, sid)});
    }
  }
  
  function find_name(){
   [root].forEach(collapse); //iterate each node and collapse
   find(root,25);
   find(root,31);
   update(root);
  }
//------------------


var margin = {top: 25, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
 width = 10000 - margin.right - margin.left,
 height = 5000 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 
var i = 0,
 duration = 750,
 rectW = 100,
    rectH = 30,
 root;
var enteredId = 7402;

//zoom functionality 
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
 .nodeSize([110, 50]);
 
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) { return [d.x + rectW / 2, d.y + rectH / 2]; }); 
    
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .call(zoom)
 .on("wheel.zoom", null) //disable zooming on mouse wheel scroll
   .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 //create a name-based map for the nodes
 //which starts with an empty object and iterates over the data array, adding an entry for each node
 //for the flat array
 var dataMap = data.reduce(function(map, node) {
 map[node.sid] = node;
 return map;
 }, {});

 //iteratively add each child to its parents, or to the root array if no parent is found
 //for the flat array
 var treeData = [];
 data.forEach(function(node) {
  // add to parent
  var parent = dataMap[node.parent];
  if (parent) {
   // create child array if it doesn't exist
   (parent.children || (parent.children = []))
    // add node to child array
    .push(node);
  } else {
   // parent is null or missing
   treeData.push(node);
  }
 });

 root = treeData[0];
 root.x0 = height / 2;
 root.y0 = 0;
//------------------------------------------------------
 var nodes = tree.nodes(root);
 function collapseLevel(d) {
  if (d.children && d.depth > 23) {
   d._children = d.children;
   d._children.forEach(collapseLevel);
   d.children = null;
  } else if (d.children) {
   d.children.forEach(collapseLevel);
  }
 }
  root.children.forEach(collapseLevel);//iterate each node and collapse excluding node zero
   
//------------------------------------------------------
 update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");
 
function zoomed() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
   links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
   .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  //vertical tree by swaping y0 and x0
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "node")
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")"; })
   .on("click", click)
 .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          var g = d3.select(this); // The node
          // The class is used to remove the additional text later
          var info = g.append('text')
             .classed('info', true)
             .attr('x', 20)
             .attr('y', 10)
             .text(function(d) { return d.name_ar + " " + d.sid }); // need to put good background for tooltip
 })
 .on("mouseout", function() {
          // Remove the info text on mouse out.
          d3.select(this).select('text.info').remove()
 });
  ;

nodeEnter.append("rect")
        .attr("width", rectW)
        .attr("height", rectH)
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

 nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", rectW / 2)
        .attr("y", rectH / 2)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name_ar; })
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);

//vertical
var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

    nodeUpdate.select("rect")
        .attr("width", rectW)
        .attr("height", rectH)
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
   .style("fill-opacity", 1);

// Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
//vertical 
var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")"; })
   .remove();

    nodeExit.select("rect")
        .attr("width", rectW)
        .attr("height", rectH)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1);
    nodeExit.select("text");

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
   .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
   .attr("class", "link")
   .attr("d", function(d) {
  var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
  return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
   });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("d", function(d) {
  var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
  return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
   })
   .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
 d.x0 = d.x;
 d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
 d._children = d.children;
 d.children = null;
  } else {
 d.children = d._children;
 d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
//-------------------------------------
</script>
```

```css
 .node {
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 .node circle {
   fill: #fff;
   stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-width: 3px;
 }

 .node text {
   font: 14px sans-serif;
 }

 .link {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #ccc;
   stroke-width: 2px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Tree Example</title>
    <header>
  <button onclick="find_name()">find</button>
 </header>
   
   </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error in the first question "The code generates an error in the console "Error: attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(undefined,undefi" is due to the SID being character.  I converted it to integer and no error is generated.